Why PHP code debugging not worked in VSCode
Guess this theme repeated here 1000 times, but I didn't find why VSCode cannot debug PHP code.

Latest VSCode with all required PHP extensions (PHP Debug also). Windows 11.
php --version:

PHP 8.3.9 (cli) (built: Jul  2 2024 18:17:57) (NTS Visual C++ 2019 x64)
Copyright (c) The PHP Group
Zend Engine v4.3.9, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v8.3.9, Copyright (c), by Zend Technologies
    with Xdebug v3.3.2, Copyright (c) 2002-2024, by Derick Rethans


xdebug section in php.ini is:

[xdebug]
zend_extension=xdebug
xdebug.mode=debug
xdebug.client_host=127.0.0.1
xdebug.client_port=9003
xdebug.start_with_request = yes
xdebug.discover_client_host = true
xdebug.log_level = 0


VSCode launch.json:

{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Listen for Xdebug",
            "type": "php",
            "request": "launch",
            "port": 9003
        }
    ]
}


netstat -tan | grep 9003:

  TCP    0.0.0.0:9003           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       InHost
  TCP    127.0.0.1:57536        127.0.0.1:9003         TIME_WAIT       InHost
  TCP    127.0.0.1:57537        127.0.0.1:9003         TIME_WAIT       InHost
  TCP    127.0.0.1:57538        127.0.0.1:9003         TIME_WAIT       InHost
  TCP    127.0.0.1:57541        127.0.0.1:9003         TIME_WAIT       InHost
  TCP    127.0.0.1:57542        127.0.0.1:9003         TIME_WAIT       InHost
  TCP    127.0.0.1:57543        127.0.0.1:9003         TIME_WAIT       InHost
  TCP    127.0.0.1:57544        127.0.0.1:9003         TIME_WAIT       InHost
  TCP    127.0.0.1:57546        127.0.0.1:9003         TIME_WAIT       InHost
  TCP    127.0.0.1:57547        127.0.0.1:9003         TIME_WAIT       InHost
  TCP    [::]:9003              [::]:0                 LISTENING       InHost


Start Laravel Development Server, put debug breakpoint in right place, then open page in Firefox (with Xdebug helper set in "Debug" mode) - nothing debugged, just ordinal execution.



Get rid of xdebug.log_level = 0 (by default it would be level 7) 2) Enable Xdebug log, start your debug and try to debug. Then check the Xdebug log and see what it has to say -- if it tries to connect at all and what the response is. 3) netstat -tan | grep 9003 -- that's nice... but which app/process is actually listening on that port? Make sure it's VSCode (run the same when VSCode is closed, maybe you have some other app already on that port)

